# Pass parameters to Get request on swiftUI

Tags: c#, .net, swiftui, httprequest, webapi

I'm having trouble with passing in parameters to a get request. This request is intended to return a list of warehouses after the user entered some search parameters such as Date, State, ZIP and/or warehouse number, which is the only mandatory field. So when the search button is pressed the query is executed, but im getting this error:

```
2021-04-19 15:49:00 +0000
2021-11-02 13:06:44.670511-0600 WAREHOUSE_IOS-Master[3142:186324] GET method must not have a body
2021-11-02 13:06:44.670799-0600 WAREHOUSE_iOS-Master[3142:186324] Task <C7839029-C527-490E-8747-137012285F14>.<3> finished with error [-1103] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1103 "resource exceeds maximum size" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=resource exceeds maximum size, 
error: invalidResponse
```

Okay so what im doing is passing a body to the get request that includes the search parameters as such:

```
struct WarehouseBody : Codable {
    
    let dateRegistration : String?
    let state : String?
    let zip : String?
    let warehouseNumber : String
}
```

and I'm expecting a response of this type:

```
struct WareHouseResponse: Codable {
    let status: String?
    let code: Int?
    let responseCode, message: String?
    let error: Bool?
    let errorMessage: String?
    let result: Result?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "Status"
        case code = "Code"
        case responseCode = "ResponseCode"
        case message = "Message"
        case error = "Error"
        case errorMessage = "ErrorMessage"
        case result = "Result"
    }
}
```

but according to what I've reading on other posts this is not the correct way of using a get request, but I really really need to do some testing. Is there a way that I can achieve this without needing to alter the backend? Just to mention that I ´m also the developer of the backend (c# using .net framework and dapper)so if the easiest way is to achieve this is by altering it I can also do that. Any ideas are very much appreciated.
On the backend I was thinking of implementing a post Request that sends the search parameters to the server and then a get request that pulls out the requested information, but I don't know if that's the correct approach. But this not feasible at the moment because the Web API are already publish and I cannot re publish with the changes at the moment, and is really urgent to test the response so that's why I would like to know if all this can be done from the front end first. Thank you very much for all the help!

Thank you very much for your help!

EDIT: Also I forgot to mention that the api has been previously tested on POSTMAN and is working perfectly.

Comment: In a `GET` request, parameters are usually encoded in the url -- eg `https://example.com/?myParam=myValue`. It seems like what you're looking to do is a `POST` request.

Comment: The current request doesn’t support POST request, so I need to change this on the backend?

Comment: Perhaps. Or maybe URL encode your parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS 13. you cannot pass in parameters to a `GET` request. There’s no easy way around this. You need to change your request from a `GET` to a `POST` on the backend. In my case, this was an easy task because I had access to the API source— but, if you don’t, just ask the backend team to change it, and pass in the parameters as in any other `POST` request. That should work.